# AngularJS: Set value for options in ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-options

I have boolean property for Customer called `IsMarried`
I want to use `<select>` tag as bellow:

```
<select name="isMarried" id="isMarried" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.isMarried" ng-options="statue for statue in maritalStatues"></select>
```

How should I change the ng-options, since I want to set `1` for `Yes` and `0` for `No` in options. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have `0` & `1` for respective statuses

**Markup**

```
<select name="isMarried" id="isMarried" 
   class="form-control" ng-model="customer.isMarried" 
   ng-options="statue.value as statue.description for statue in maritalStatues">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.maritialStatus = [ { value : 1, description : "Yes"}, {value : 0, description : "Unmarried"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. in your controller

```
$scope.maritalStatues = [{statusKey: 0 , statusTitle : 'Unmarried'},{statusKey: 1 , statusTitle : 'Married'}];
```

on your view page

```
 <select name="isMarried" id="isMarried" class="form-control" ng-model="customer.isMarried" ng-options="status.statusKey as status.statusTitle for status in  maritalStatues">
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided much info about the object but if our object array is like :

```
$scope.maritialStatus = [ { id : 1, name : "Married"}, {id:2,name: "Unmarried"}]
```

then you can write your select like this:

```
<label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="customer.isMarried">
      <option ng-repeat="status in martialStatus" value="{{status.id}}">{{status.name}}</option>
    </select>
```